# Is there a concise way to generate a continuous less-than relationship?

Tags: symbols, operators, sequence

Actually, I have a ton of variables, Let me simplify it to 4 in this post.

```
vars = {a, b, c, d};
0 < Less @@ vars < 10
```

> 0 < (a < b < c < d) < 10

Notice that the result has a `()`, which will lead to some unexpected results. And what I'm hoping for is `0 < a < b < c < d < 10`. Is there any easy method?

Comment: `Less @@ {0, Splice[vars], 10}`

Comment: ^ Note that `Splice` changed meaning in 12.1 to work as above, and before that it used to have a totally different function with application to string templates. If you happen to be using an older version, you could use `Less @@ {0, Sequence @@ vars, 10}` instead of the code above with `Splice`.

Comment: @Syed Magic usage...

Comment: `Less @@ Flatten[{0, vars, 10}]`

Comment: `0 < Less @@ vars < 10//Flatten`